# GNU make: получить целевые файлы с расширением (суффиксом) как у зависимых файлов

Tags: makefile, gnumake

Имеются некоторые файлы с одинаковым базовым именем, но различающиеся расширением.
Например:
`foo.ex1`
`foo.ex2`
`foo.txt`

Требуется, после некоторых операций *над каждым* зависимым файлом, получить на выходе из Makefile файлы с базовым именем как у цели, но с расширением как у зависимых файлов.
Например:
`foo.bar.ex1`
`foo.bar.ex1`
`foo.bar.txt`

С MSFT `nmake.exe` это делается просто и непринуждённо.
Например, с использованием команд командной оболочки:

```makefile
foo.bar.txt : foo.???
    ! @<<tmp.bat
for /F "usebackq" %%G in (`dir /b $?`) do (
     for /F "usebackq delims=" %%H in (`type %%G ^|findstr /bvl "Remove me gently"`) \
        do (1>>$(@B)%%~xG echo %%H)
 )
<<
```

Или это же на PowerShell:

```makefile
PS = PowerShell.exe
PSFLAGS = -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command

foo.bar.txt : foo.???
    ! @$(PS) $(PSFLAGS) $$ext=(Get-Item $?).Extension; (Get-Content $?) -notmatch 'Remove me gently' \
        ^| Out-File $(@B)$$ext
```

В общем, в обоих случаях, на выходе получаем такие файлы:
`foo.bar.ex1`
`foo.bar.ex2`
`foo.bar.txt`

Т. е. требуется выполнить некоторые операции ***над каждым зависимым файлом***, и результат сохранить в новом файле. Наименование нового файла формируется из базового имени цели (т. е., в данном случае, foo.bar) и расширения файла зависимости, над которым сейчас выполняется операция.

Подскажите, пожалйста, есть ли что‐то подобное в GNU `make`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPD: Из каждого файла подходящего под маску `foo.???` создаём файл `foo.bar.???`

```
# создаём список файлов
FILES := $(patsubst foo.%,foo.bar.%,$(wildcard foo.???))

# объявляем что нам нужно получить все эти файлы
default: $(FILES)

# правила могут быть шаблонными
# объявляем зависимость выходных файлов от входных
foo.bar.%: foo.%
    grep -v 'Remove me gently' $< > $@ || true
```

Вывод

```
$ make
grep -v 'Remove me gently' foo.ex1 > foo.bar.ex1 || true
grep -v 'Remove me gently' foo.ex2 > foo.bar.ex2 || true
grep -v 'Remove me gently' foo.txt > foo.bar.txt || true
```

---

Я не очень понимаю что вы тут хотите получить.
Может что-то такое?

```
FILES = $(patsubst foo.%,foo.bar.%,$(wildcard foo.???))

default:
    @echo $(FILES)
```

Выхлоп:

```
$ ls
foo.ex1  foo.ex2  foo.txt  Makefile
$ make
foo.bar.ex1 foo.bar.ex2 foo.bar.txt
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Надо выполнить некоторые операции (наример, удалить строку из файла) над каждым зависимым файлом и сохранить результать под новым наименование, которое формируется из базового имени файла цели и расширения файла зависимости над которым сейчас выполняется операция. Буду сейчас пробовать Ваш вариант. Блогодарю ещё раз.

Comment: @Restorer обновил ответ

Comment: Да, благодарю. Попробую сейчас. А скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли возможность формировать новое имя файла «на лету»? Т. е. без предварительного объявления переменной (макроса), а использовать эту функцию makefile непосредсвенно в блоке команд? Примерено так, как это делается в `nmake.exe`. Я сейчас читаю руководство по GNU make, там есть ещё такие функции как `$(addsuffix)` , `$(basename)` and `$(suffix)`. Можно ли как‐то использовать эти функции?

Comment: @Restorer насколько я понимаю ваш код на nmake у вас там простой цикл по списку файлов. Я не очень понимаю зачем тут в таком случае вообще make/nmake если вы просто по сути написали bat-скрипт. Конечно в makefile тоже можно написать скрипт, но почему бы тогда просто не написать скрипт без всяких make?

Comment: да, Вы почти правы. На сколько я понимаю, фалософия GNU make несколько отличается от MSFT nmake. Удивителен мир unix... Что‐то подобное, я имею в виду встроенные функции, появились в nmake только в MSVC 2022. Что ж, будем осваивать.

Comment: В попытке понять как это всё работает, пробовал вот такую конструкцию `for f in $(wildcard $?) ; do echo $(suffix $$f) ; done` , но получаю пустрой `echo`. Скажите, переменные цикла не разворачиваются во встроенных функциях GNU make, да?

Comment: Alexey Ten, скажите, пожалуйста, а можно ли Ваш пример сделать как‐то без шаблонных правил?

Answer (score 1):

Например вот так:

```
all: $(patsubst foo.%,output/foo.bar.%,$(wildcard foo.*))

output:
        mkdir -p $@

output/foo.bar.%: foo.% | output
        cp $< $@
```

`output` здесь нужен чтобы создать отдельную папку и сложить в нее результат. Если вам не нужно, можно убрать.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Нет, отдельный каталого не нужен. Уберу. Попробую Ваш вариант.